# How do you pick up your Romanian passport from the NYC Consulate (once it's ready online)?

Tags: usa, passports, application-status, romanian-citizens

I looked online at the link the consulate provided and I see that my passport is available for pick-up.

Do I need to schedule an appointment to pick it up? Are there specific days / hours during which I can pick the passport?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you called the Romanian Consulate in New York and asked? Or sent them an email?

Comment: Yes, I've tried calling quite a few times and also sent emails.!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as stated on the website, all Consular services are by appointment only.
See http://newyork.mae.ro/en/node/409#null for information on how to request one.